# While compiling Tests Groovy:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

when I want to run Groovy script in IntelliJ, this error happens:
Information:Groovyc: While compiling Tests Groovy:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContextat

Comment: Probably because you're using JDK 11 or superior version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)